# Query dot after number

Tags: sql, sql-server, number-formatting

```
select cast(round(((select sum(UCRET) TUTAR 
                    from ARAC_CIKIS 
                    where YEAR(CIKIS_ZAMANI) = YEAR(GETDATE()) 
                      and MONTH(CIKIS_ZAMANI) = MONTH(GETDATE()) 
                      and DAY(CIKIS_ZAMANI) = DAY(GETDATE()))), 2) as numeric(36, 0))
```

I have this query which returns:

```
11000,00
```

How can I get it to show

```
11.000,00
```

Answer (score 0):

It is a display format. You can use Format() function for that if you like. ie:

```
select format(11000, '#0,000.00', 'tr-TR');
```

You can even add lira sign if you use 'C' for format. ie:

```
select format(11000, 'C', 'tr-TR');
```

Answer (score 0):

for example

```
SELECT FORMAT(11000.00, 2);
```